# Game where you play as the Nutcracker and swat fairies

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I remember playing, or at least spectating, a PC game in the mid-to-late 2000s set in the fantasy world of *The Nutcracker*. In it, you would play as the eponymous Nutcracker and swat/kill various fairies flying around you as if they were flies. The game was from a second-person perspective--the Nutcracker is looking directly at the player and is immobile save for its arms. Was this a simple flash game from the time or a more developed one?

Comment: What was the control mechanism? There was a Playstation 2 game using the Eye Toy (I think that's the name) camera, and the player actually moved to make the on-screen avatar move (that is, it didn't use the hand-held controller). I don't know the name of the game, however.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: first person is seeing through the character's eyes, second person is seeing through the eyes of the player, third person is any other perspective (eg a floating camera). The only games that qualify for 2nd person are AR (not VR). And I'm not sure AR even qualifies. The answer below is 3rd person. Not trying to criticize but it gave me a chance to explain an obscure term.

Comment: @SkySpiral7 I will adjust my terminology going forward (though I won't be editing my question so I can remember my mistake).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the Flash game [*Nutcracker vs. The Sugarplum Fairies*](http://www.jetcitystudios.com/public/content/dtoys/dtoys3.html) by Jet City Games.

You play as the Nutcracker and swat fairies.

Comment: Wow, it's all coming back. What an era for gaming.